# Splicing Matrix Permutations Done in Blocks in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, permutation

I am looking for a way in python to: permute thru only certain blocks of a matrix at a time.

Specifically, I want a matrix, where:

1. the diagonal consists of square blocks of size n of all zeros
2. divding the rest of the rows and columns into equally size blocks, and substituting in a matrix the size of that block into each one of those blocks.
3. running a test on this new matrix, if it fails, substitute a new matrix into P

Here is an image of what I want if that is not so clear:
http://s27.postimg.org/syimn1zvn/photo.jpg

where P[i] is the matrix defined by one row of:

```
    for per in itertools.permutations(range(n)):
        matrix = [[0 for x in xrange(n)] for x in xrange(n)]
        for i, j in enumerate(per):
            matrix[i][j] = 1
        print matrix
```

Should one of these rows not give the satisfied result once input into the matrix I would like to replace that block with the 2nd row.

Now, I have done similar work where I was working only with splicing particular lines, and then running through all the possible permutations, e.g.:

```
     row = list(perm_unique([1,0])) #this gives the unique permutations of the items
     zs = list((0,0))

     for a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12 in product(row, repeat=12):

        M, N, O, P, Q, R, = ([] for i in range(6))

        M = list(chain(zs,a1,a2))
        N = list(chain(zs,a3,a4))
        O = list(chain(a5,zs,a6))
        P = list(chain(a7,zs,a8))        
        Q = list(chain(a9,a10,zs))
        R = list(chain(a11,a12,zs))

        A = list()
        A.append(M)
        A.append(N)
        A.append(O)
        A.append(P)
        A.append(Q)
        A.append(R)

        B = np.asarray(A)
```

Unfortunately, I am finding it extremely hard to find a method to do this same process but with blocks or small matrices instead of simple lines. If anyone could give me any ideas, or criticism. I have only been learning how to code Python for less than 2 weeks, so would love to hear advice from anyone.

Comment: Use numpy, which has a native syntax for addressing blocks of a matrix.

Comment: This question looks ridiculous now that I have a couple years experience.

Comment: (The last edit on this, a couple of years ago, was so drastic it would generally be regarded here as vandalism. It is probably better on the prior version, so I have rolled back).

Comment: You're welcome @par, all part of the service. `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When all your matrices are lists of lists of equal length, you can write a function to place a submatrix on a larger matrix at a certain position:

```
def place_submatrix(M, A, i, j):
    """Place submatrix A in M wit top left corner (i, j)"""

    for ii in range(len(A)):
        for jj in range(len(A)):
            M[i + ii][j + jj] = A[ii][jj]
```

This is not dynamic like `L.append(X)` or `L += [X]`. It requires that a suitably big matrix already exists. For example:

```
M = [[0 for x in xrange(9)] for x in xrange(9)]

A = [
    [[44, 98, 23], [56, 93, 54], [83, 92, 72]],
    [[72, 37, 58], [10, 17, 42], [40, 36, 74]],
    [[48, 72, 39], [34, 98, 56], [87, 33, 66]],
    [[90, 61, 16], [50, 98, 52], [81, 56, 77]],
    [[13, 62, 86], [40, 53, 29], [39, 51, 14]],
    [[23, 36, 91], [22, 76, 27], [58, 12, 91]]
]

pos = [(0, 3), (0, 6), (3, 0), (3, 6), (6, 0), (6, 3)]

for p, a in zip(pos, A):
    row, col = p
    place_submatrix(M, a, row, col)
```

Then add another loop around this to permite the list of submatrices, `A`.